# how to move a spark model from one spark installation to another?

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

I have an ALS model that I train on one spark installation.  I persist as so:

```
model.save(sc, './recommender_model')
```

On the filesystem it looks like this:

```
$ find ./recommender_model
./recommender_model
./recommender_model/metadata
./recommender_model/metadata/_SUCCESS
./recommender_model/metadata/._SUCCESS.crc
./recommender_model/metadata/.part-00000.crc
./recommender_model/metadata/part-00000
./recommender_model/data
./recommender_model/data/product
./recommender_model/data/product/part-r-00001-406655c7-5c12-44d4-9b39-d5367ccabe29.gz.parquet
./recommender_model/data/product/_common_metadata
./recommender_model/data/product/.part-r-00000-406655c7-5c12-44d4-9b39-d5367ccabe29.gz.parquet.crc
./recommender_model/data/product/.part-r-00001-406655c7-5c12-44d4-9b39-d5367ccabe29.gz.parquet.crc
./recommender_model/data/product/_SUCCESS
./recommender_model/data/product/._metadata.crc
./recommender_model/data/product/._SUCCESS.crc
./recommender_model/data/product/._common_metadata.crc
./recommender_model/data/product/part-r-00000-406655c7-5c12-44d4-9b39-d5367ccabe29.gz.parquet
./recommender_model/data/product/_metadata
./recommender_model/data/user
./recommender_model/data/user/_common_metadata
./recommender_model/data/user/.part-r-00001-f8bf36d3-2145-4af2-9780-6271d68ea25c.gz.parquet.crc
./recommender_model/data/user/_SUCCESS
./recommender_model/data/user/.part-r-00000-f8bf36d3-2145-4af2-9780-6271d68ea25c.gz.parquet.crc
./recommender_model/data/user/._metadata.crc
./recommender_model/data/user/part-r-00000-f8bf36d3-2145-4af2-9780-6271d68ea25c.gz.parquet
./recommender_model/data/user/._SUCCESS.crc
./recommender_model/data/user/._common_metadata.crc
./recommender_model/data/user/part-r-00001-f8bf36d3-2145-4af2-9780-6271d68ea25c.gz.parquet
./recommender_model/data/user/_metadata
```

I would like to move this folder to another spark installation so that I train on one spark installation and use another spark installation for predictions.

Can I simply `tar` up this folder and unpack it to the other spark instance where I can load the model? E.g.

```
model = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, './recommender_model')

my_movie = sc.parallelize([(0, 500)]) # Quiz Show (1994)
individual_movie_rating_RDD = model.predictAll(my_movie)
individual_movie_rating_RDD.collect()
```

Comment: Downvoter: why downvote?  I have no idea how to improve the question without feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed some basic testing and the approach of zipping up the whole folder and unzipping it on another machine worked well for me.